# How to create logic that will run ONLY once as long as the user is on the page (ie user does not go to a different page and come back)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Hi I've was having this problem where the logic in my Page_Load function was being called whenever my AJAX timer was triggered. Fortunately I used Update Panels to differentiate Asynch Postbacks, which now catches the calls from the AJAX timers. However, every once in awhile (I'd say maybe every 15 seconds or so), my logic in the Page_Load runs through again (I'm not sure if this is an AJAX callback that isn't being catched or is something else). How do I make it so that logic is ran once and only once, when the page is originally loaded? Note that if a user goes to a different page and then comes back to this page I want this code to run again, just not as long as they remain on the page.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Chat : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).IsInAsyncPostBack)
        {
            SendButton.Click += new EventHandler(SendButton_Click);
            if (Request.QueryString["RecID"] != null)
                Session["receivinguserid"] = Request.QueryString["RecID"];
            else
                Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
            UserCredential sendingUser = (UserCredential)Session["authenticatedUser"];
            UserCredential receivingUser = Global.Users.Find(m => m.UserID == Convert.ToInt32(Session["receivinguserid"]));
            Conversation currentConversation = new Conversation((int)sendingUser.UserID, (int)receivingUser.UserID);
            if (sendingUser.Conversations.Find(m => m.ReceivingUserID == receivingUser.UserID) == null)
            {
                Global.Users.Find(m => m.Name == (string)Session["authenticatedUsersUsername"]).Conversations.Add(new Conversation((int)((UserCredential)Session["authenticatedUser"]).UserID, Convert.ToInt32(Session["receivinguserid"])));
                Global.Users.Find(m => m.UserID == Convert.ToInt32(Session["receivinguserid"])).Conversations.Add(new Conversation(Convert.ToInt32(Session["receivinguserid"]), (int)((UserCredential)Session["authenticatedUser"]).UserID));
            }
            else
            {
                currentConversation = sendingUser.Conversations.Find(m => m.ReceivingUserID == receivingUser.UserID);
                foreach (Message m in currentConversation.ReadMessageList)
                {
                    if (m.UserID == sendingUser.UserID)
                    {
                        ChatLabel.Text += "<br> " + sendingUser.Name.ToString() + ": " + m.MessageText + " " + m.MessageDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM HH:mm");
                    }
                    else if (m.UserID == receivingUser.UserID)
                    {
                        ChatLabel.Text += "<br>" + receivingUser.Name.ToString() + ": " + m.MessageText + " " + m.MessageDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM HH:mm");
                    }
                }
                foreach (Message m in sendingUser.Conversations.Find(m => m.ReceivingUserID == receivingUser.UserID).UnReadMessageList)
                {
                    ChatLabel.Text += "<br>" + receivingUser.Name.ToString() + ": " + m.MessageText + " " + m.MessageDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM HH:mm");
                    sendingUser.Conversations.Find(t => t.ReceivingUserID == receivingUser.UserID).ReadMessageList.Add(m);
                }
                sendingUser.Conversations.Find(m => m.ReceivingUserID == receivingUser.UserID).UnReadMessageList.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
    public void UpdateChat(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserCredential sendingUser = (UserCredential)Session["authenticatedUser"];
        UserCredential receivingUser = Global.Users.Find(m => m.UserID == Convert.ToInt32(Session["receivinguserid"]));
        foreach (Message m in sendingUser.Conversations.Find(c => c.ReceivingUserID == receivingUser.UserID).UnReadMessageList)
        {
            ChatLabel.Text += "<br>" + receivingUser.Name.ToString() + ": " + m.MessageText + " " + m.MessageDate.ToString("ddd, dd MMMM HH:mm");
            Global.Users.Find(u => u.UserID == (int)sendingUser.UserID).Conversations.Find(t => t.ReceivingUserID == receivingUser.UserID).ReadMessageList.Add(m);
        }
        Global.Users.Find(m => m.UserID == (int)sendingUser.UserID).Conversations.Find(t => t.ReceivingUserID == receivingUser.UserID).UnReadMessageList.Clear();
    }
```

And the HTML:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Chat.aspx.cs" Inherits="Chat" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
  <a>
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
   <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server">
   </asp:Timer>
  </a>
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
   <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tim" EventName="Tick" />
   </Triggers>
   <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer ID="tim" Interval="5000" Enabled="true" OnTick="UpdateChat" runat="server"></asp:Timer>
    <asp:Label ID="ChatLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
  <asp:TextBox ID="MessageTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Button ID="SendButton" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClientClick="return false"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!IsPostback)
{

 // code to run only once

}
```

IsPostback checks if you passing it first time => (IsPostback = false) or as a result of a postback that came later on as a result of a fired event => (IsPostback = true), in the code above we are reversing the IsPostback using the **!** to make the false case fall into place.  for more detailed info have a look at this [IsPostback Explained](http://net-informations.com/faq/asp/ispostback.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Set a session variable when the code is first run, then only run the code if the session variable is null.

It will be null when the code first runs but not null the rest of the time.

Comment: But what if the user visits another page and then returns to this page? Then the session variable will not be null and the logic that is supposed to run when the page loads will not run.

Comment: You need to update your question then as you said, "Once and only once"

Comment: I apologize for my ambiguity. What I meant was I wanted this logic to run ONCE when the page loads and not run multiple times as long as the user is on the page. If the page user goes to a different page and then comes back, I want this logic to run again. I just don't want it to run whenever AJAX or anything else does a postback.